# Is it possible to decorate include(...) in django urls with login_required?

Tags: django, url, functional-programming, decorator

I have a few restricted areas on the site, for which I would like to specify `login_required` decorator. However I would like to do that once per inclusion in main urls.py, not per individual url in included urls.py

So instead of:

/private/urls.py:

```
(r'^profile/$', login_required(profile)),
```

I'd do something along the lines:

/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                      ...
                      (r'^private/', login_required(include('private'))),
                      )
```

Except that it doesn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It is doable, and in fact I just found [two](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2532/) [snippets](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2607/) for this.

### Solution #1

The first snippet by [cotton](http://djangosnippets.org/users/cotton/) substitutes `RegexURLPattern` and `RegexURLResolver` with custom implementations that inject given decorator during `resolve` call.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import RegexURLPattern, RegexURLResolver
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from myproject.myapp.decorators import superuser_required

class DecoratedURLPattern(RegexURLPattern):
    def resolve(self, *args, **kwargs):
        result = super(DecoratedURLPattern, self).resolve(*args, **kwargs)
        if result:
            result.func = self._decorate_with(result.func)
        return result

class DecoratedRegexURLResolver(RegexURLResolver):
    def resolve(self, *args, **kwargs):
        result = super(DecoratedRegexURLResolver, self).resolve(*args, **kwargs)
        if result:
            result.func = self._decorate_with(result.func)
        return result

def decorated_includes(func, includes, *args, **kwargs):
    urlconf_module, app_name, namespace = includes

    for item in urlconf_module:
        if isinstance(item, RegexURLPattern):
            item.__class__ = DecoratedURLPattern
            item._decorate_with = func

        elif isinstance(item, RegexURLResolver):
            item.__class__ = DecoratedRegexURLResolver
            item._decorate_with = func

    return urlconf_module, app_name, namespace
```

You need to use it like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ...
    (r'^private/', decorated_includes(login_required, include(private.urls))),
)
```

(Note that `include` parameter can't be a string with this method.)

### Solution #2

Another solution by [sjzabel](http://djangosnippets.org/users/sjzabel/), which I ended up using myself, is applied *outside* `patterns` call so it can be used with strings and has a slightly different syntax. The idea is the same, though.

```
def required(wrapping_functions,patterns_rslt):
    '''
    Used to require 1..n decorators in any view returned by a url tree

    Usage:
      urlpatterns = required(func,patterns(...))
      urlpatterns = required((func,func,func),patterns(...))

    Note:
      Use functools.partial to pass keyword params to the required 
      decorators. If you need to pass args you will have to write a 
      wrapper function.

    Example:
      from functools import partial

      urlpatterns = required(
          partial(login_required,login_url='/accounts/login/'),
          patterns(...)
      )
    '''
    if not hasattr(wrapping_functions,'__iter__'): 
        wrapping_functions = (wrapping_functions,)

    return [
        _wrap_instance__resolve(wrapping_functions,instance)
        for instance in patterns_rslt
    ]

def _wrap_instance__resolve(wrapping_functions,instance):
    if not hasattr(instance,'resolve'): return instance
    resolve = getattr(instance,'resolve')

    def _wrap_func_in_returned_resolver_match(*args,**kwargs):
        rslt = resolve(*args,**kwargs)

        if not hasattr(rslt,'func'):return rslt
        f = getattr(rslt,'func')

        for _f in reversed(wrapping_functions):
            # @decorate the function from inner to outter
            f = _f(f)

        setattr(rslt,'func',f)

        return rslt

    setattr(instance,'resolve',_wrap_func_in_returned_resolver_match)

    return instance
```

Call it like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ...
)

urlpatterns += required(
    login_required,
    patterns('',
        (r'^private/', include('private.urls'))
    )
)
```

Both work fine but I prefer the latter syntax.

Comment: This functionality is also available in a package, [django-decorator-include](https://github.com/twidi/django-decorator-include).

Comment: @JoshKelley 's comment has the perfect answer. Easiest usage EVER!

Answer (score 6):

An alternative:

```
def decorate_url(decorator, urlconf):
    '''Recreates the url object with the callback decorated'''
    # urlconf autoresolves names, so callback will always be a function
    return url(urlconf._regex, decorator(urlconf.callback), urlconf.default_args, urlconf.name)

def decorate_include(decorator, urlpatterns):
    urls = [
        decorate_url(decorator, urlconf) if not isinstance(urlconf, RegexURLResolver) else decorate_include(decorator, urlconf)
        for urlconf in urlpatterns[0]
    ]
    return (urls,) + urlpatterns[1:]

# usage
urlpatterns += patterns(
    '',
    url('^my-url/', decorate_include(login_required, include('app.urls'))),
)
```

A slightly more complex version, that supports multiple decorators:

```
def compose_decorators(decorators, wrappee):
    for wrapper in decorators:
        wrappee = wrapper(wrappee)
    return wrappee


def decorate_url(urlconf, *decorators):
    ''' Decorate a url structure with decorators '''
    revdecorators = decorators[::-1]  # we want the function call to read left to right

    # urlconf autoresolves names, so callback will always be a function
    return url(
        urlconf._regex,
        compose_decorators(revdecorators, urlconf.callback),
        urlconf.default_args,
        urlconf.name
    )

def decorate_include(urlpatterns, *decorators):
    ''' Decorate a patterns structure with decorators '''
    urls = [
        decorate_url(urlconf, *decorators) if not isinstance(urlconf, RegexURLResolver) else decorate_include(urlconf, *decorators)
        for urlconf in urlpatterns[0]
    ]
    return (urls,) + urlpatterns[1:]

# usage
urlpatterns += patterns(
    '',
    url('^my-url/', decorate_include(include('app.urls'), login_required, decorator2)),
)
```

Comment: Can someone make this to work on Django 1.9 - Python 3? Thanks in advance!

Comment: just change urlconf._regex to urlconf.pattern.regex.pattern

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a very old question so for anyone who is wondering about the same, there is a very simple solution now.

Install `django-decorator-include` via `pip install django-decorator-include`.

Here is how to use it:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from decorator_include import decorator_include


urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^private/', decorator_include(login_required, 'private')),
]
```

Here is the link to the [GitHub documentation](https://github.com/twidi/django-decorator-include).

And here is the link to [Pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/django-decorator-include/)

Comment: Sadly it looks like this library has fallen behind in support for newer Django versions.

Answer (score 2):

`login_required` is meant for wrapping view callable, not include(), and looking at source code:

http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.1.1/django/conf/urls/defaults.py#L9

-- I don't think there is an easy way to use default (or even custom) `login_required` with include() to achieve what you want to achieve.

Writing this, I think that the reasonable approach would be to use some "login required middleware", like this one: http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1179/ and forget about decorating urls in urls.py.

Answer (score 2):

> Feature is being discussed in issue [#25409](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25409). There will be major rework for URLs and is planned for Django 1.10 release.

Comment: Seems the discussion is not going anywhere :( In the meanwhile I found https://github.com/twidi/django-decorator-include

Answer (score 2):

you can use decorate_url

see here

http://github.com/vorujack/decorate_url

you can install it by pip

```
pip install decorate_url
```

example show on github