# Disabling django cache for a specific app

Tags: django, caching

For 90% of my project, I want caching. Caching is pretty great.

However there's always an exception. I want one particular app in my project to not use any caching, for any of its views.

What would be great is if there was a way to enable caching for the entire site, but disable it for an app. I'm aware of the `@never_cache` decorator on a per view basis, is this my best bet or is there a less granular way?

Comment: Have a look at decorating the `urls` for your app: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9318962/396300

Comment: That's neat and all, but seems a little hackish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's more clear to just use the @never_cache decorator, but I found this snippet https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/355/ you can use it on your app urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import url
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

def never_cache_patterns(prefix, *args):
    pattern_list = [], tterns,
    for t in args:
        if isinstance(t, (list, tuple)): 
            t = url(prefix=prefix, *t)
        elif isinstance(t, RegexURLPattern):
            t.add_prefix(prefix)

        t._callback = never_cache(t.callback)
        pattern_list.append(t)

    return pattern_list


urlpatterns = never_cache_patterns('',
    (r'foo/$', 'myview')
)
```

Comment: I think I agree that it's more clear, and I don't much like the idea of making my URLs logicy.

Comment: Yeah, is not the most elegant solution

Comment: I'll accept this based on the first 11 words. Seems like there isn't a "proper" way.