# Decorating URLs include (group of urls)

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I need to decorate a URL include in django application.
I need something like:

```
url(r'^billing/', decorator_include(require_role(['admin','billing']), include('billing.urls'))),
```

I've tried the library called [django-decorator-include](https://github.com/jeffkistler/django-decorator-include) (which is pretty outdated) and all solutions from [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307926/is-it-possible-to-decorate-include-in-django-urls-with-login-required) but all failed.

In all cases I get exception:

```
TypeError at /
'module' object is not iterable
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8006/
Django Version: 1.8.3
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'module' object is not iterable
Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/decorator_include/__init__.py in _get_urlpatterns, line 61
```

Is this even possible to decorate url include? I don't want to dozens of views separately.

Comment: i am not sure, but shouldn't it be `billing.urls` instead of `include('billing.urls')`?

Comment: @dhke, have you read my question?

Comment: @dease Not thoroughly enough, obviously. Scratch that comment ...