# Django 2.0 and decorator_include - problems with reverse urls

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-2.0

I use `django 2.0.7` in my project with `django-decorator-include` app (version 2.0).

My urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from decorator_include import decorator_include


urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path('', include('web.urls', namespace='web')),
    path('backoffice/', decorator_include([login_required,], 'backoffice.urls', namespace='backoffice')),

) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My `backoffice.urls`:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from backoffice import views

app_name = 'backoffice'

urlpatterns = (
    path('', views.DashboardView.as_view(), name='dashboard'),
)
```

`backoffice` is added to **INSTALLED_APPS**.

In my views (in app `web` for example) I am able to do reverse URL, for example in my login view I do `return redirect('backoffice:dashboard')` and it works just perfectly - its redirecting to /backoffice/.

Problem is when I try to do reverse urls in my templates. In one of my templates, when I add code:

```
<li class="featured"><a href="{% url 'backoffice:dashboard' %}">{% trans 'Open dashboard' %}</a></li>
```

I get django error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
'backoffice' is not a registered namespace
```

I suppose that problem is related to django-decorator-include, because if I change my include to standard django url include:

```
path('backoffice/', include('backoffice.urls', namespace='backoffice')),
```

it works just fine, and I am able to get reverse urls in templates again.
What should I do? Maybe its a bug in django-decorator-include? Any ideas how can I solve that?

Comment: This is an old version, but try [decorator_include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307926/is-it-possible-to-decorate-include-in-django-urls-with-login-required)

Comment: @CarlBrubaker that's the problem - I currently use it

Comment: Did you check the link? Someone else ran into that problem.

Comment: I did, where exactly someone has reported the same issue with django-decorator-include?

Comment: Did you see if it works without the `[ ]` around `login-required`?

Comment: I need to pass a list of decorator. That is supported by plugin

Comment: Yes, it’s just another elimination. If it does work, then there is an issue with taking lists. If it doesn’t work, you probably want to contact the plugin maker.