# passing decorator in django url gives 'tuple' object is not callable error

Tags: python, django

```
def UrlRequired(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'id' in request.session and 'url' not in request.session:
            request.session.delete()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
        else:
            return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrap
```

this is my custom decorator which i am passing through project level url so it would be accessed by all the functions who are extending the respective url but it is giving such error.

```
TypeError at /home/

'tuple' object is not callable
```

url :

```
url(r'home/',UrlRequired(include('app.urls',namespace='homee'))),
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to decorate include(...) in django urls with login\_required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307926/is-it-possible-to-decorate-include-in-django-urls-with-login-required)

Comment: `include()` is returning a `tuple` and your decorator in the case above is calling this tupple. Davit gave you a proper link to do what you want.